# jQuery Slider floating? issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

For my website i have created a jQuery slider which slides through some colored sections. I want two to slide upwards and the center one to slide downwards.

With my code the other colored sections are floating below so they are pushed up after a time. 
However when i make my center one to slide downwards i dont think i can float the other sections above to be pushed down later.

Here is a fiddle showing my code and previewing the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/4negcm6u/

```
//slider 2
//settings for slider

var height2 = -600;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide2 = 1;

//cache DOM elements
var $slider2 = $('#slider2');
var $slideContainer2 = $('.slides2', $slider2);
var $slides2 = $('.slide2', $slider2);

var interval;



if($(window).width() >= 481){

function startSlider2() {


    interval = setInterval(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 480){
 $slideContainer2.animate({'margin-top': '-='+height2}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide2 === $slides2.length) {
                currentSlide2 = 1;
                $slideContainer2.css('margin-top', 0);
            }
        });
      }
    }, pause);

}


function pauseSlider2() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}


$slideContainer2

    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider2)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider2)


startSlider2();



}
```

Anything will help alot, Thanks.